# Nested objects in response not logging to console

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, object

My server gets a response from another server with a document from a mongodb database with a body similar to

```
{
    messageDetails: {
        body: "hello"
    },
    customerDetails: {
        cstmrFirstName: 'Random',
        cstmrLastName: 'Name',
    },
}
```

But the response with the body is being logged to the console as:

```
{
  messageDetails: [Object],
  customerDetails: [Object],
}
```

How can I log the full object to the console with each object's properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [console.dir](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/dir).  To print with unlimited depth, use `{depth: null}` option:

```
console.dir(body, {depth: null});
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `console.log(JSON.stringify(body))`
Checkout [MDN doc JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for more details

Answer (score 2):

To anyone using Deno (I didn't test this anywhere else):

To make `console.dir` disregard depth limits, pass a second argument with depth set to `Infinity`:
`console.dir(body, { depth: Infinity });`

*Based on @A1exandr Belan's answer, but changing `null` to `Infinity`, since it seems `console.dir` takes `null` as `0` and outputs just a simple `[Array]`.*

Answer (score 1):

const util = require('util')

console.log(util.inspect(objectName, {showHidden: false, depth: null, colors: true}))